# Regex capturing group not working as intended

Tags: java, regex

I've been struggling for two days to get this to work, but I just can't (I'm terrible at regular expressions :S).

```
${test}[arg]
```

From this text, I need to retrieve two different things: `test` and `arg`. To do it, I have created this regex:

```
(\$\{(\b[a-zA-Z0-9.]+\b)\})(\[(.+)\])?
```

With that example, it works. However, if I try this other text: `${test}[arg1] - ${test2}[arg2]`, I just get one match with 2 groups: `test` and `arg1] - ${test2}[arg2`, instead of getting 2 different matches: one with groups `test` and `arg1`, and the other with groups `test2` and `arg2`.

I hope you can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a classic example of why the `.+` combination can be evil. Use a negated character set instead:

```
(\$\{(\b[a-zA-Z0-9]+\b)\})(\[([^]]+)\])
                              ^^^
```

You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/8v0mNh/1).

---

Compare the behavior of the two expressions:

- [Match anything greedily](https://regex101.com/r/tMOMgO/1/debugger). For the second match, the regex matches anything greedily. It will match anything until it reaches the end of the string, and then has to backtrack until it finds a `]`. As soon as it finds a `]`, it stops, hence you end up with `[arg1] - ${test2}[arg2]` as a match.
- [Match anything but a `]`](https://regex101.com/r/8v0mNh/1/debugger). Here the regex is matching anything that is not a `]`, therefore at every step is checks whether the next is a `]` or not. For the second match, you can see that as soon as it finds a `]`, it stops.