# Regex to match text between single, double and triple quotes

Tags: regex

I have a text file that I want to parse strings from. The thing is that there are strings enclosed in either single (`'`), double (`"`) or 3x single (`'''`) quotes within the exact same file. The best result I was able to get so far is to use this:

```
((?<=["])(.*?)(?=["]))|((?<=['])(.*?)(?=[']))
```

to match only single-line strings between single and double quotes. Please note that the strings in the file are enclosed in each type of quotes can be either single- or multi-line and that each type of string repeats several times within the file.

Here's a sample string:

```
<thisisthefirststring
'''- This is the first line of text
- This is the second line of text
- This is the third line of text
'''
>

<thisisanotheroption
"Just a string between quotes"
>

<thisisalsopossible
'Single quotes

Multiple lines.

With blank lines in between
'
>

<lineBreaksDoubleQoutes
"This is the first sentence here

After the first sentence, comes the blank line, and then the second one."
>
```

Comment: Can you share an example string?

Comment: Sorry, what's your question? Do you basically need to add the `'''` case in your regex?

Comment: Also note that using a reluctant quantifier (`.*?`) is not efficient, use a negated character set instead. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52019534/3390419) or [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41269355/3390419) for an explanation.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness: You can't use negated character class for `'''` like in `'''blah'blah'''`

Comment: That's true, however OP states the strings are contained in *either* single, double etc. Therefore that string would not be expected.

Comment: @UnbearableLightness: `'''blah'blah'''` is a valid string `blah'blah` enclosed by triple single quote `'''`

Comment: Can't we wait for OP's examples? How can you tell what is valid and what is not?

Comment: No example string, no language or app/tool tags (since the pattern syntax depends of them), no answers to questions in comments = close the question as *too broad*. Even if you make an effort to build a pattern and you try to explain your problem.

Comment: Good to have added examples. But can single quotes be found inside double quotes (i.e. `"blah ' blah"`)? Or  double quotes inside single (i.e. `'blah " blah'`)? Or `'''blah ' blah '''`? Or escaped one `'blah\'blah'`? or any combination of them?

Comment: I think the possible "odd" options are double quotes within single quotes - `'blah " blah'` and having `'` or `"` between 3x single quotes, so `''' blah " blah ' blah '''`

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
((?:'|"){1,3})([^'"]+)\1
```

[Test it online](https://regex101.com/r/SlMu18/1)

Using the group reference `\1`, you can simplify your work

Also, to get only what is *inside* of the quotes, use the 2nd group of the match

Comment: This is matching `"''blah"''` or `"""bla"""` or `'"blah'"`

Comment: This doesn't match `'''blah'blah'''`

Comment: Thank you for pointing it @Toto you are right! But as UnbearableLightness commented, I will wait for OP before making any changes,

Comment: This does work for the most part. However, it matches the quotes as well, while ideally I need just the strings between them.

Comment: Maybe here are the limits of pure (without programming) regex reached. For more complex substitutions, I like to use: https://github.com/sl5net/SL5_preg_contentFinder/

Comment: I agree, would be much easier if anything but pure regex was an option. However, I am using this to configure a 3rd party service to do what I need and my only option is regex.

Answer (score 1):

This regex: `('{3}|["']{1})([^'"][\s\S]+?)\1`

does what you want.

Some results:

[image]

Comment: i found a problem in my regex above.  it does not find
`'"blah"'`

Answer (score 1):

Using Notepad++, you can use: `('''|'|")((?:(?!\1).)+)\1`

**Explanation:**

```
('''|'|")           : group 1, all types of quote 
(                   : group 2
    (?:(?!\1).)+    : any thing that is not the quote in group 1
)                   : end group 2
\1                  : back reference to group 1 (i.e. same quote as the beginning)
```

Here is a screen capture of the result.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that may work for you.

```
^(\"([^\"\n\\]|\\[abfnrtv?\"'\\0-7]|\\x[0-9a-fA-F])*\"|'([^'\n\\]|\\[abfnrtv?\"'\\0-7]|\\x[0-9a-fA-F])*'|\"\"\"((?!\"\"\")[^\\]|\\[abfnrtv?\"'\\0-7]|\\x[0-9a-fA-F])*\"\"\")$
```

Replace the triple double quotes with triple single quotes.  See it in action at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/aGoSsg/3).

Answer (score 1):

### Named Group Version

**Avoids problems when used in larger expressions by explicitly referring to the name of the group storing the last found quote.**

Should work for most systems:

```
(?<Qt>'''|'|")(.*?)\k<Qt>
```

.NET version:

```
(?<Qt>'''|'|"")(.*?)\k<Qt>
```

**Works as follows:**

1. `'''|'|"`: Check first for `'''`, then `'`, and finally `"`.  Done in this order so `'''` has priority over `'`.
2. `(?<Qt>'''|'|"")`: When matched, place the match in `<Qt>` for later use.
3. `(.*?)`: Capture the results of a [lazy](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quickstart.html#morequants) search for 0 or more of anything `.*?` - will return empty strings.  To prevent empty strings from being returned, change to a lazy search for 1 or more of anything `.+?`.
4. `\k<Qt>`: Search for the value last stored in `<Qt>`.